# letsencrypt kubernetes: How can i include ClusterIssuer in cert-manager using helm chart instead of deploying it as a separate manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, certificate, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I would like to add ssl support to my web app (wordpress) deployed on kubernetes. for that i deployed cert-manager using helm like following:

```
helm upgrade \
  cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v1.9.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true \
  --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerName=letsencrypt-prod \
  --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerKind=ClusterIssuer \
  --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerGroup=cert-manager.io \
  --create-namespace \
  jetstack/cert-manager --install
```

Then i deployed wordpress using helm as well, while values.yml look like :

```
#Change default svc type
service:
  type: ClusterIP

#ingress resource
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: app.benighil-mohamed.com
  path: /
  annotations:
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  extraTls:
  - hosts: 
      - "{{ .Values.ingress.hostname }}" #  ie: app.benighil-mohamed.com
    secretName: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.ingress.hostname }}" #ie: wp-app.benighil-mohamed.com
```

However, when i check certifiactes and certificaterequests i got the following:

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/flux/ingress $ kubectl get certificate -n app -owide
NAME                               READY   SECRET                             ISSUER             STATUS                                         AGE
wp-benighil.benighil-mohamed.com   False   wp-benighil.benighil-mohamed.com   letsencrypt-prod   Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist   25m
vscode ➜ /workspaces/flux/ingress

vscode ➜ /workspaces/flux/ingress $ kubectl get certificaterequests -n app -owide
NAME                                     APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER             REQUESTOR                                         STATUS                                                                                             AGE
wp-benighil.benighil-mohamed.com-45d6s   True                False   letsencrypt-prod   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   Referenced "ClusterIssuer" not found: clusterissuer.cert-manager.io "letsencrypt-prod" not found   27m
vscode ➜ /workspaces/flux/ingress
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Cert-Manager resources have logs. 
Certificate Issuer logs will help you find you and us the reason.

Comment: hello @Sushilinux actually i have to create ClusterIssuer manifest manually. At the beggining i  thought that the options i gave for cert-manager helm chart will do the job (ie: installs clusterIssuer automativally) but no.